# How to embed s/\A{/LB/ in the EXPR of s{...}{EXPR}e?

Tags: regex, perl

I've read 'Quote and Quote-like Operators' in `man perlop` but can't figure out how to use `s/.../EXPR/e` if EXPR contains code which itself contains a substitution involving both \A and the outer substitution delimiters:

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\{/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

works and prints `LBfoo}`, I guess as expected.

If I try to anchor using `\A` it won't parse:

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\{/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

gets `Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\A{ <-- HERE /`

Adding additional backslashes before `\A` does not help.

Adding additional backslashes before `\{` does not seem to work either:

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\\{/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

gets `Substitution replacement not terminated` (reasonably enough), but

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\\\{/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

compiles but does not match (output is `{foo}` not `LBfoo}`).

Adding additional backslashes alternates between the "not terminated" error and silently not matching.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: You need to escape the `{` because it's a delimiters, and because it's in a pattern. But you can't to do both. Simple solution: `s{.+}{ $& =~ s/^\x7B/LB/r }er`

Comment: @ikegami: Interestingly, switching to `^` is already enough.

Comment: @choroba, Ah. That's because it doesn't allow `\A{`, but it allows `^{`. Still, I don't like unescaped `{`

Comment: @ikegami: `^\{` works, not `^{`.

Comment: @choroba, Because it's escaping a delimiter, the `\ ` is removed during the process of finding the end of the literal. If you put `\A\{`, you end up with `\A{`. This is deemed unacceptable (cause there are many `\x{` constructs for some letter `X`.) If you put `^\{`, you end up with `^{`. This is deemed acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following broken code:

```perl
s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\{/LB/;$_ }er
```

Let's start by simplifying that to the following:

```perl
s{.+}{ $& =~ s/\A\{/LB/r }er;
```

One of the first things Perl needs to do to parse this is to find the end of the operator. The delimiters of the outer substitution are `{` and `}`, so the `\{` in the replacement expression is escaping a delimiter. In the same way that `"a\"b"` produces the string `a"b`, your substitution has the following replacement expression:

```perl
 $& =~ s/\A{/LB/r
```

Note that the `\` is gone, since it was used to escape a delimiter.

So we're left with `\A{`, and that isn't legal. (`\x{` for some letter `x` is either recognized like in `\x{}`, `\N{}`, `\b{}`, or reserved to allow this in the future.) This is why your program doesn't work. The simple solution is to avoid using `{` by using `\x7B` in lieu.

```perl
s{.+}{ $& =~ s/\A\x7B/LB/r }er;
```

You could also use a different delimiter.

```perl
s<.+>< $& =~ s/\A\{/LB/r >er;
```

Alternatively, there are hacks you could use.

```perl
s{.+}{ $& =~ s/^\{/LB/r }er;     # Inner subst is `s/^{/LB/r`
s{.+}{ $& =~ s/\A \{/LB/xr }er;  # Inner subst is `s/\A {/LB/xr`
```

Comment: Thank you for replying; I do wish you would reread your words and think carefully about the payoff you experienced from choosing the particular language and tone in the reply.   I come here to learn (and occasionally teach) and  make life enjoyable at the same time.   Scolding or shaming people is rarely helpful.

Comment: The $& =~ s/.../.../r trick would be ideal if that was the only substitution;  the real application is more complicated and I did not want to clobber pos($_) and hence the local $_.

The question remains (in my mind at least): Why is `\A{`  not legal while `\A {` is?  The trick of using /x is very nice.  But I would like to understand why the space is needed to parse.

Comment: 1. Doesn't clobber `pos($_)`. Doesn't even use `$_`. /// 2. You can chain. `$& =~ s/.../.../r =~ s/.../.../r`. But it was about making the code simpler to deal with for the answer. /// 3. Using any variable other than `$_` would make more sense anyway. 4. Already explained. `\A{` is not valid (because many `\x`-type constructs can be followed by `{`). But there's nothing illegal about `\A {`.

Comment: @jimav I thought this was a purely academic question. I would not recommend this in production code, for several reasons. It is hard to predict results, it is unnecessary, it involves eval (almost always bad and not needed), and it's kind of hard to maintain.

Comment: @Bork, Nothing in this answer involves `eval`. (You're thinking of `/ee`, maybe?) And code in the replacement expression isn't hard to predict, or hard to maintain. It's in fact a very simple solution to problems that would be otherwise very complex. As always, you can move the code to a sub (or more than one) if it gets too complex. But shying away from using `/e` is not an answer. You can into complex escaping issues, yes, which is why the solution I presented dodges the need for escaping entirely.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.  I see now why quote-parsing bomb out becuase it's looking for \<letter>{...}.   I didn't understand that before.    This answer and the accompanying comment thread pretty well explains what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `{` (or any other delimiter) because you want to use it literally in the outer substitution. But you also need to escape it because it needs to be escaped in the inner substitution. Unfortunately, Perl doesn't make it possible to change the escape character for the inner substitution, so you can't do it.

There are more ways how to quote things, e.g. `\Q`:

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\Q\{\E/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

(the `\E` is not needed here)

Or, use an `\x` escape:

```
perl  -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A\x7b/LB/;$_ }er;
```

Or, use a variable:

```
perl -E '$lb = "\\{"; say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A$lb/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

Using a character class works, too:

```
perl -wE 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A[\{]/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

Even turning on `/x` and separating them by a space helps:

```
perl -E 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/\A \{/LB/x;$_ }er;'
```

I tried running the one-liners with `-Mre=debug` to see what's going on, and Perl reports `\A{`, not `\A\{` being the problem. Interestingly, `^\{` leads to `^{` which is fine.

```
perl -wE 'say "{foo}" =~ s{.+}{local $_=$&; s/^\{/LB/;$_ }er;'
```

Note that other delimiters have the same problem if they're special in regexps (and they don't work with `^`, either), i.e.

```
perl -wE 'say "[foo]" =~ s[.+][local $_=$&; s/^\[/LB/;$_ ]er;'  # Error
perl -wE 'say "(foo)" =~ s(.+)(local $_=$&; s/^\(/LB/;$_ )er;'  # Error
perl -wE 'say "<foo>" =~ s<.+><local $_=$&; s/^\</LB/;$_ >er;'  # OK!
```